# Canvas code not working in IE9 - probably alpha or globalCompositeOperation issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, alpha

I have a javascript routine which is designed to flickering sun rays.  The routine creates 'numRays' rays, then begins to overwrite the rays using globalCompositeOperation = 'copy' and drawing a transparent ray over the oldest ray.

You can see the program here:[Sun Ray Page](http://infinitemonkeys.dyndns.tv/Better_Rays/animation.html)

JSFiddle.net code located here:[JSFiddle Sun Rays](http://jsfiddle.net/infinitemonkeys/Y5Y48/) (I'm not sure how to make it work on JSFiddle, so if someone can fix my fiddle, I'd appreciate that, too.)

(Note: I have left a yellow stroke around the erased rays for diagnostic purposes, so you can see them executed.)

The code works in Chrome and Firefox, however, in IE9, the original rays are not drawn when I leave the erase section active.  In other words, if I remark out the section that creates the erase stroke, the ray fills occur.  If I do not, then only the erase strokes occur.

I have tested various fixed alpha values and IE9 seems to handle them perfectly.  I've set both sections to globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over' and still do not get the original rays.

Can someone help me correct this code to work on IE9?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working in jsfiddle because you never call `init()`

IE9 is probably breaking script execution on the line:

`ctx.rotate(rayArray[currentRay]); // Rotate to the rayAngle`

Because it throws an error the first 11 times it is called, because you keep trying to access a value that is undefined the first 10-11 times through.

So I moved your incrementing code down to after the `ctx.rotate` statement and added the init. It doesn't have errors in IE or FireFox, but I have no way of knowing if its what you intended:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Y48/18/

Comment: numRays rays are drawn at random angles.  After each is drawn, another with 0 alpha is drawn to erase the oldest.
So, for numRays=5, rays at angle rayArray[0]-[4] are drawn. rayArray[0] is recalled & drawn over.  The counter must increment before the 2nd rotate or it will erase the ray just drawn. e.g. When rayArray[4] is drawn, rayArray[0] is erased.

The jsfiddle works as it should. I've reduced numRays, slowed animation, and removed the visible line around erase rays.  It still does not work with IE9 whether the increment is moved as you describe or all rayArray[] are filled with 0 values.